# Change the text of the bounty grace period email

Tags: feature-request, bounty, email

The email titled "Bounty Grace Period Started - Stack Overflow" is confusing, as it implies that the grace period started when the email was sent.

However, the email is sometimes sent hours later after the bounty grace period starts.

Therefore, it'd be preferable to include the start time in the title and the message as well--e.g. "Bounty Grace Period Started at 12:00 UTC - Stack Overflow"

Comment: @Kendra Nah it's 100% a dupe, they're both complaining that the email arrival time isn't useful to determine the end of the grace period, and they both ask for the actual end time to be included in the email title.